# Material UI comptaibility with React v.18

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using react v.18.2.0 and makeStyles material UI(I am using v4 of material UI) is not working. I'm not sure how to make my background turn black. There is no error in code when I run it, but my background does not change to black. How do it correctly?

```
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom';
import  Header  from './components/Header';
import Homepage from './Pages/Homepage';
import CoinPage from './Pages/CoinPage';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';



function App() {
  
   const useStyles=makeStyles(()=>({
    App:{
      backgroundColor:'black',
    }
   })
   );
  const classes= useStyles();
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className={classes.App}>
      <Header/>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Homepage />} />
        <Route path='/coins/:id' element={<CoinPage/>}/>
      </Routes>
        
      
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
    
  )
}

export default App;
```

I was expecting my react home webpage background to turn black but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have you tried moving your styles outside of the component?
2. Check for CSS specificity issues that might override your backgroundColor style, like inline styles or other CSS classes. Also, confirm that classes.App is correctly applied to your div element by inspecting it with browser developer tools.

   ```
   import React from 'react';
   import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
   import Header from './components/Header';
   import Homepage from './Pages/Homepage';
   import CoinPage from './Pages/CoinPage';
   import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

   // Define useStyles outside of the App component
   const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
     app: {
       backgroundColor: 'black',
     },
   }));

   function App() {
     const classes = useStyles();
     return (
       <BrowserRouter>
         <div className={classes.app}>
           <Header/>
           <Routes>
             <Route path='/' element={<Homepage />} />
             <Route path='/coins/:id' element={<CoinPage />} />
           </Routes>
         </div>
       </BrowserRouter>
     );
   }

   export default App;
   ```